# How to move an icon through different points?

Tags: javascript, web, web-animations

[This website](https://www.rhinoafrica.com/en/safaris/great-wildebeest-migration) has an excellent animated map showing the migration patterns of wildebeest in the Serengeti. Unfortunately, they animated their map using Flash.

I wanted to know whether there were alternatives for doing something similar, perhaps with Javascript. I found a plugin called [Two.js](https://two.js.org/) however the documentation isn't great and it seems to be a bit overkill for what I need.

Does anyone know of any good resources or examples they could kindly link me to?

Comment: [HTML5 Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) might be a good start for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

Using HTML5 canvas and animate your objects using `window.requestAnimationFrame()`;

Animate the dom, here you could use [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) or [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API).

With HTML5 canvas you work with raster image (pixels) instead using the DOM you could animate any HTML elements including also SVG which is vector.